# Error setting the selected value from a select list

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML select list where one can chose an option.

```
<select name='price' id='price'>
<option value='' >Select....</option>
<option value='0-50,000' selected>0-50,000</option>
<option value='50,000-100,000'>50,000-100,000</option>
<option value='100,000-150,000'>100,000-150,000</option>
<option value='150,000-200,000'>150,000-200,000</option>
<option value='200,000 and above'>200,000 and above</option>
<option value='see all'>See All</option>
</select>
```

When this list is submitted via a HTML submit button, this list shows again in another page. Now, I want the option the user selected to be new selected value. I am doing this:

```
<select name='price' id='price'>
<option value='{$_POST['price']}'>{$_POST['price']}</option>
<option value='0-50,000'>0-50,000</option>
<option value='50,000-100,000'>50,000-100,000</option>
<option value='100,000-150,000'>100,000-150,000</option>
<option value='150,000-200,000'>150,000-200,000</option>
<option value='200,000 and above'>200,000 and above</option>
<option value='see all'>See All</option>
</select>
```

But values are appearing twice. The option the user selected is shown as the selected and still appears in the list. For example, we now have something like this:

```
0-50,000 (this is the selected value)

0-50,000

50,000-100,000

100,000-150,000

150,000-200,000

200,000 and above
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: It may come as a surprise, but the attribute to mark an option as selected is actually `selected`. So the option element must have this attribute: `<option selected="selected" value="...">...</option>`.

Comment: because here you are printing an extra option `<option value='{$_POST['price']}'>{$_POST['price']}</option>`

Comment: you can get reference  from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257490/how-to-display-selected-item-at-drop-down-list/24257831#24257831]

Answer (score 0):

In other page, make sure the selected option has `selected="selected"`

```
<select name='price' id='price'>\
<option value='' >Select....</option>
<option selected="selected" value='0-50,000'>0-50,000</option>
<option value='50,000-100,000'>50,000-100,000</option>
<option value='100,000-150,000'>100,000-150,000</option>
<option value='150,000-200,000'>150,000-200,000</option>
<option value='200,000 and above'>200,000 and above</option>
<option value='see all'>See All</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No, the the option the user selected in previous page should now be made the new selected value in the next page. How do I do that?

Comment: @radioactive : you want to make a new value ? or select the value. If you want to make a new value then what you are doing is right. It will obviously get repeated as your HTML(in the next page) already has the same value. I am still not clear, what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/**
     * Takes To values (First for option value Second for value to be compare)
     * @param Srting $option stores Option Value String
     * @param String $value Stores to be compare
     * @return String
     * @access public
     */
function selectBoxSelection($option, $value) {
        if ($option == $value) {
            return "selected";
        }
    }



 <select name='price' id='price'>

<option value='0-50,000' <?php echo selectBoxSelection('0-50,000', $_POST['price']);?> >0-50,000</option>
<option value='50,000-100,000' <?php echo selectBoxSelection('50,000-100,000', $_POST['price']);?> >50,000-100,000</option>
<option value='100,000-150,000' <?php echo selectBoxSelection('100,000-150,000', $_POST['price']);?> >100,000-150,000</option>
<option value='150,000-200,000' <?php echo selectBoxSelection('150,000-200,000', $_POST['price']);?> >150,000-200,000</option>
<option value='200,000 and above' <?php echo selectBoxSelection('200,000 and above', $_POST['price']);?> >200,000 and above</option>
<option value='see all' <?php echo selectBoxSelection('see all', $_POST['price']);?> >See All</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name='price' id='price'>
    <option value='' >Selec</option>
    <option value='0-50,000'<?php if($_POST['price']=='0-50,000'){echo "selected==selected";}?>>0-50,000</option>
    <option value='50,000-100,000'<?php if($_POST['price']=='50,000-100,000'){echo "selected==selected";}?>>50,000-100,000</option>
    <option value='100,000-150,000'<?php if($_POST['price']=='100,000-150,000'){echo "selected==selected";}?>>100,000-150,000</option>
    <option value='150,000-200,000'<?php if($_POST['price']=='150,000-200,000'){echo "selected==selected";}?>>150,000-200,000</option>
    <option value='200,000 and above'<?php if($_POST['price']=='200,000 and above'){echo "selected==selected";}?>>200,000 and above</option>
    <option value='see all'<?php if($_POST['price']=='see all'){echo "selected==selected";}?>>See All</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just a quick and constructive criticism if I may. I noticed you give out a lot of solutions while helping many solve their issues and that I am sure is putting a smile on many people's faces. However, you stand at receiving upvotes if an explanation is given as to why people's code are failing on them, possibly now and by future visitors to the question. Showing where errors are made also shows others visiting questions, what exactly was done in order to resolve it/them.

Comment: At that time I was new to SO . now I learn how to give ans at SO and how to make our answer more effective.

Answer (score 0):

instead of your code,

```
<select name='price' id='price'>
<option value='{$_POST['price']}'>{$_POST['price']}</option>
<option value='0-50,000'>0-50,000</option>
<option value='50,000-100,000'>50,000-100,000</option>
<option value='100,000-150,000'>100,000-150,000</option>
<option value='150,000-200,000'>150,000-200,000</option>
<option value='200,000 and above'>200,000 and above</option>
<option value='see all'>See All</option>
</select>
```

try like this,

```
<select name='price' id='price'>
<option value='' >Select....</option>
<?php foreach ($arr as $key=>$value)
{
         if($key == $_POST['price'])
         {
            echo "<option selected value=$key>$value</option>";
            unset($arr[$key]);
         }
         else
         echo "<option value=$key>$value</option>";
}?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it :

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="testsel.php">

<select name='price' id='price'>
<option value='' >Select....</option>
<option value='0-50,000' <?php if(isset($_POST["price"]) && $_POST["price"]=="0-50,000") print "selected"; ?>>0-50,000</option>
<option value='50,000-100,000' <?php if(isset($_POST["price"]) && $_POST["price"]=="50,000-100,000") print "selected"; ?>>50,000-100,000</option>
<option value='100,000-150,000' <?php if(isset($_POST["price"]) && $_POST["price"]=="100,000-150,000") print "selected"; ?>>100,000-150,000</option>
<option value='150,000-200,000' <?php if(isset($_POST["price"]) && $_POST["price"]=="150,000-200,000") print "selected"; ?>>150,000-200,000</option>
<option value='200,000 and above' <?php if(isset($_POST["price"]) && $_POST["price"]=="200,000 and above") print "selected"; ?>>200,000 and above</option>
<option value='see all' <?php if(isset($_POST["price"]) && $_POST["price"]=="see all") print "selected"; ?>>See All</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST["price"]))
    print $_POST["price"];

?>
```

Save this file as "testsel.php" and view. It will serve the purpose.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)